# what does question mark means in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types

what does "?" mean in MVC , when we write it with data type for example

```
public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
```

what does "?" shows? and what will be difference if i will not write "?"  ?

Comment: nullable, it can get null values which you can check with `variable.HasValue`

Comment: I was reading about this a few hours ago. It allows for nullable types but if Grade is a class I don't see why it needs to have the ? operator

Comment: @pcnThird see this 

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I am performing this tutorial

Answer (score 7):

If you want to make any property nullable then we add question marks "?"

`public Grade? Grade { get; set; }` --> Grade property will accept null value also.

`public Grade Grade { get; set; }` --> no null value allowed for this property

Answer (score 4):

`Grade?` is the same as `Nullable<Grade>`.  It's a [C# language feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), not specific to MVC.

Answer (score 2):

In the link you provided in the comments, Grade represents an enum which is a value type. Value types don't have the ability to point to null, so it needs to be suffixed with the ? symbol to represent a null value. It's essentially the same as saying:

```
public Nullable<Grade> Grade { get; set; }
```

More examples:

```
int a = null; //not allowed
int b? = null; //allowed
string refType = null; //allowed
int x? = 2;
int y? = 2;
```

Keep in mind that if you try to perform an operation on nullable types, the operators will be lifted:

```
book areEqual = x == y;
```

which translates to:

```
bool areEqual = (x.HasValue && y.HasValue) ? (x.Value == y.Value) : false;
```

That means that the nullable type can use the operators from the original value type.

Answer (score 2):

`?` represents a nullable type. Nullable types represent value-type variables that can be assigned the value of `null`. You *cannot* create a `nullable` type based on a reference type, because reference types already support `null`.

From the link you provided for your tutorial:

> The Grade property is an enum. The question mark after the Grade type
>   declaration indicates that the Grade property is nullable. A grade
>   that's null is different from a zero grade — null means a grade isn't
>   known or hasn't been assigned yet

So, in the same example `Enrollment` is a reference type which, is nullable by default. So won't need explicit `?` when declaring objects of that class.

This is a valid nullable declaration. You can assign `null` to it:

```
int? num = null;
```

You can also do a:

```
int y = num.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Where `y` will get whatever value `num` contains (if it contains a value), otherwise `null` which is default for nullable types.

You can expicitly check if it contains `null` by:

```
num.HasValue();
```

You get values out of nullable typed variables like this:

```
int y = num.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The id may be null while passing as a parameter to action method.

Comment: post it as comment